# I don't want radio button check change C# Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

Two radio button in may program.

names HEX and ASCII

When user checked radio button, text is chanege

```
    void rdo_HEX_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rdo_HEX.Checked)
        {
            try
            {                    
                textbox1.Text = AsciiToHex(textbox1.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                textbox1.Text = HexToAscii(textbox1.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

But I don't want occur checkedChange evnet When an error occurs...

if error occurs when checkedChange, just radio button check is change and text is retained.

For example,

First text is 'ABCD' and ASCII is checked and it convert to '41424344' when HEX radio button is checked.

And '4142434' convert to Ascii, error ouccur, so text is '4142434' but ASCII radio button is checked..

So user check HEX radio button '4142434' convert to '34313432343334'

I dont want this...I want not change checked radio button when error occur.

How can I do?

Comment: you're catching the exception in the CheckChanged... so you can't not call the event when there is an exception cause it's already been called.

What are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the one checked after disabling the `CheckChanged`

```
void rdo_HEX_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rdo_HEX.Checked)
    {
        try
        {                    
            textbox1.Text = AsciiToHex(textbox1.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            rdo_HEX.CheckedChanged -= rdo_HEX_CheckedChanged;
            rdo_HEX.Checked = false;
            rdo_HEX.CheckedChanged += rdo_HEX_CheckedChanged;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            textbox1.Text = HexToAscii(textbox1.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            rdo_HEX.CheckedChanged -= rdo_HEX_CheckedChanged;
            rdo_HEX.Checked = true;
            rdo_HEX.CheckedChanged += rdo_HEX_CheckedChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if im understanding you correctly you dont want to keep the radio-button checked in case an error is thrown. Im not seeing the implementation on both buttons here, im just seeing one of them. So you will have to replicate this for your ascii radio button.

```
    void rdo_HEX_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rdo_HEX.Checked)
        {
            try
            {
                textbox1.Text = AsciiToHex(textbox1.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                rdo_HEX.Checked = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                textbox1.Text = HexToAscii(textbox1.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```